# Simple javascript program with while condition stuckked

Tags: javascript, performance

```
var i = 1;                                               //simple varibles with value
var value1 = 2700;
var value2 = 2550;

var constant1 = value1;
var constant2 = value2;

while (value2 <= value1) {                              //condition
value1 = parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(constant1);
value2 = parseFloat(value2) + parseFloat(constant2);
i = parseFloat(i) + 1;
    if (value2 >= value1) {
    break;}
}
document.getElementById('n').value = i;
```

A simple programm where loop is not running and output is blank (going for infinite loop)

I want to run the loop 
    value1 = parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(constant1);
    value2 = parseFloat(value2) + parseFloat(constant2);
    i = parseFloat(i) + 1;
while value2 remains less than value 1

Comment: what is your question ? What are to trying to do ? Add more information

Comment: `value2` will always be less than `value1`, meaning your loop never ends. If we imagine `value1` to equal *2* and `value2` to equal *1*, on the first iteration `value1` will change to *4* and `value2` will change to *2*. On the second iteration, `value1` will change to *8* and `value2` will change to *4*, etc.

Comment: Just a side note, all those `parseFloat`s are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

You are always adding `value1` and `value2` to itself, so it will always will be `value2 < value1`.

Your code converts to

```
var value1 = 2700;
var value2 = 2550;
var i = 1;

while (true) {
    value1 += value1;
    value2 += value2;
    i++;

    if (false) {
        break;
    }
}

document.getElementById('n').value = i;
```